# Ether stolen from contracts

Tags: solidity, vulnerability

Can anyone explain  what is exactly the point of this claim

https://medium.com/@rtaylor30/how-i-snatched-your-153-037-eth-after-a-bad-tinder-date-d1d84422a50b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author mentions on his update below that this was a fictional post, but based on what actually happened in the parity hack.

He points out technically the vulnerability in the contracts and how simply it could be exploited.  I would think the point is to make people aware of the hacks and the vulnerabilities so that developers can avoid them in the future.

Since the language and ecosystem are so new, and we're in a completely different kind of programming where all code is immutable and public (complete open book to any would-be hacker), the community is fairly quick to respond, support, and educate others.